# How to make Java with Applet project into .exe file

Tags: java, applet

How to make Java with Applet project into  .exe file. So it can run an any computer.

Comment: A Java applet would always require a Java runtime environment to run.  So the Windows machine would need a JRE installed, and it would also have to allow applets to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible.

It is not possible to create an exe that will run on any computer.  Period.

It is possible to create an exe that will run on a Windows machine (I hesitate to say *any* Windows) but that exe won't run on Linux or Mac OSX ... or any machine that is not a x86 or x86-64 machine (depending on how you built the exe).

It is possible to run a Java application (from a JAR file) on any machine with Java preinstalled.

It is possible to create an exe wrapper for a Java application (see [How can I convert my Java program to an .exe file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file)), but the exe won't that can run on *any* machine.  Like all exe files, it will only run on specific operating systems / hardware architectures.  And converting to an exe like this may cause some aspects of Java not to work.

I would recommend these alternatives:

- Distribute your application as a JAR file, and leave it up to the user to download and install a JRE separately.  (That is NOT hard to do.)
- Use an installer-builder (such as InstallAnywhere) to create installers for your application for the platforms you want to support.  Use the option for embedding a JRE in the installer.

---

The other issue is that applet support is going to be removed entirely from Java pretty soon.  Indeed, it has already been de-supported in most modern browsers.  You should be looking to rewrite your UI code using AWT / Swing, JavaFX, HTML5 or something else.

Comment: Lots of ways.  What do you use to build your Java code?   (And I am not your "bro"!)

Comment: I use Jdk1.8.0_151

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.  But **assuming** that you are using the JDK command line tools (rather than an IDE or a build tool), the `jar` command is the one you should use to build a JAR file.  Read the manual entry for it.